# Как вывести содержимое папки таблицей(например, TreeView Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

Написал программу, которая выводит содержимое каталога.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как вывести эту информацию таблицей или в treeView?
'''

```
from tkinter import *
import time, os

def list_files(startpath):
print(startpath)
count = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startpath):
    if dir != '.git':
        level = root.replace(startpath, '').count(os.sep)
        indent = ' ' * 4 * (level)
        secs = os.path.getmtime(startpath)
        file_time = time.gmtime(secs)
        listbox.insert(END,'{}{}/    Date - {}:{} {}.{}.{};'.format(indent, 
        os.path.basename(root), file_time[3], file_time[4], file_time[2], file_time[1], 
        file_time[0]))
        subindent = ' ' * 4 * (level+1)
        for f in files:
            full_file_path = os.path.join(root, f)
            secs = os.path.getmtime(full_file_path)
            file_time = time.gmtime(secs)
            secs = os.path.getmtime(full_file_path)
            file_time = time.gmtime(secs)
            size = os.path.getsize(full_file_path)
            listbox.insert(END,'{}{} Date - {}:{} {}.{}.{};  size - {} '.format(subindent, f, file_time[3], file_time[4], file_time[2], file_time[1], file_time[0], round(size/1024/1024, 4)))


def clicked():
         res = txtaddr.get()
list_files(res)



window = Tk()
window.title("Содержимое папки")
window.geometry('570x250')
lbl = Label(window, text="Адрес папки: ")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
txtaddr = Entry(window, width=40)
txtaddr.grid(column=1, row=0)
listbox = Listbox()
listbox.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W+E, padx=5, pady=5)
btn = Button(window, text="Отобразить!", command=clicked)
btn.grid(column=2, row=0)

window.mainloop()
```

'''

Comment: А как вы таблицей собирались выводить? Для неё нет нормального виджета

Answer (score 2):

Через `ttk.Treeview`. Могу показать пример своего кода. **`(Только для Windows)`**, рабочий. Только он все подгружает, даже другие диски

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as msgbox
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter import ttk
import os,shutil,subprocess
from datetime import datetime
import string
from ctypes import windll
from getpass import getuser as WinGetUsername
def get_drives():
    drives = []
    bitmask = windll.kernel32.GetLogicalDrives()
    for letter in string.ascii_uppercase:
        if bitmask & 1:
            drives.append(letter+':\\')
        bitmask >>= 1

    return drives
win=Tk()
win.title('FotonExplorer')
win.iconphoto(True, PhotoImage(file='img\\app_icon.png'))
class FileFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self,window=None,master=None,width=80,height=25):
        self.notepad_exist=False
        self.window=window
        if os.path.isfile('C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe'):
            self.notepad_exist=True
        self.drives=get_drives()
        self.sfl_dict={}
        self.user=WinGetUsername()
        ttk.Style().theme_use('vista')
        self._w=Frame(master)
        #ttk.Label(self._w,text='Имя').grid(row=0,column=1)
        #ttk.Label(self._w,text='Дата создания').grid(row=0,column=2)
        #ttk.Label(self._w,text='Тип').grid(row=0,column=3)
        self.cmd_img=PhotoImage(file='img\\cmd_img.png')
        self.dir_img=PhotoImage(file='img\\dir.png')
        self.newdir_img=PhotoImage(file='img\\new_dir.png')
        self.desktop_img=PhotoImage(file='img\\desktop.png')
        self.documents_img=PhotoImage(file='img\\documents.png')
        self.images_img=PhotoImage(file='img\\images.png')
        self.videos_img=PhotoImage(file='img\\videos.png')
        self.drive_img=PhotoImage(file='img\\drives.png')
        self.drives_img=PhotoImage(file='img\\drives2.png')
        self.user_img=PhotoImage(file='img\\user.png')
        self.music_img=PhotoImage(file='img\\music.png')
        self.unselect_img=PhotoImage(file='img\\un-select.png')
        self.download_img=PhotoImage(file='img\\download.png')
        self.simplefilelist=ttk.Treeview(self._w,height=25)
        self.simplefilelist.grid(row=0,column=0,rowspan=4)
        self.full_libs()
        self.simplefilelist.bind('<Button-1>',self.click2)
        ttk.Button(self._w,text='Cmd',command=self.cmd_start,image=self.cmd_img).grid(row=1,column=5)
        ttk.Button(self._w,text='Новая папка',command=self.new_dir,image=self.newdir_img).grid(row=2,column=5)
        self.img_lib=os.getcwd()+'\\img\\'
        self.filelistframe=Frame(self._w)
        self.filelistframe.grid(column=1,row=1,columnspan=3,rowspan=4)
        self.tk=master.tk
        self.listbox=ttk.Treeview(self.filelistframe,columns=("1n","2n",'3n'),height=25)
        self.listbox.heading("#0", text="             Имя",anchor=W)
        self.listbox.heading("1n", text="Дата создания",anchor=W)
        self.listbox.heading("2n", text="Тип",anchor=W)
        self.listbox.heading("3n", text="Размер",anchor=W)
        self.listbox.pack(side=LEFT)
        scrolly = Scrollbar(self.filelistframe)
        self.listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrolly.set)
        scrolly.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
        scrolly.config(command=self.listbox.yview)
        hbar=Scrollbar(self._w,orient=HORIZONTAL)
        hbar.grid(column=1,row=5,columnspan=3,ipadx=385)
        hbar.config(command=self.listbox.xview)
        self.listbox.config(xscrollcommand=hbar.set)
        self.width=width
        self.height=height
        self.files={}
        self.images=[]
        self.copy_file=os.getcwd()
        self.copy_or_cut=0
        self.notepad_plus_plus_img=PhotoImage(file='img\\notepad++.png')
        
        self.listbox.bind('<Double-Button-1>',self.click)
        self.context_menu = Menu(tearoff=0,bg='#fffff0',font=('arial',9
                                                              ))
        self.context_menu.add_command(label="Открыть", command=self.OPEN)
        self.context_menu.add_command(label="Вставить", command=self.PASTE)
        self.context_menu.add_command(label="Копировать", command=self.COPY)
        self.context_menu.add_command(label="Вырезать", command=self.CUT)
        self.context_menu.add_command(label="Переименовать", command=self.RENAME)
        self.context_menu.add_command(label="Удалить", command=self.DELETE)
        self.context_menu.add_separator()
        self.context_menu.add_command(label="Открыть в блокноте", command=lambda: self.startfile('notepad'))
        if self.notepad_exist:
            self.context_menu.add_command(label="Открыть в Notepad++", command=lambda: self.startfile('"C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe"'),font=('arial',11),image=self.notepad_plus_plus_img)
        self.listbox.bind('<Button-3>',self.context)
        os.chdir('C:\\Users\\'+self.user+'\\')
        self.full_files()
    def full_libs(self):
        for it in self.sfl_dict.keys():
            self.simplefilelist.delete(it)
        self.sfl_dict={}
        self.drives=get_drives()
        self.simplefilelist.heading("#0", text="Библиотеки и диски",anchor=W)
        self.user_column=self.simplefilelist.insert("",0,None,text='Пользователь',image=self.user_img)
        self.sfl_dict[self.user_column]='C:\\Users\\'+self.user
        self.desktop_column=self.simplefilelist.insert("",1,None,text='Рабочий стол',image=self.desktop_img)
        self.sfl_dict[self.desktop_column]='C:\\Users\\'+self.user+'\\Desktop\\'
        self.download_column=self.simplefilelist.insert("",2,None,text='Загрузки',image=self.download_img)
        self.sfl_dict[self.download_column]='C:\\Users\\'+self.user+'\\Downloads\\'
        self.docs_column=self.simplefilelist.insert("",3,None,text='Документы',image=self.documents_img)
        self.sfl_dict[self.docs_column]='C:\\Users\\'+self.user+'\\Documents\\'
        self.images_column=self.simplefilelist.insert("",4,None,text='Изображения',image=self.images_img)
        self.sfl_dict[self.images_column]='C:\\Users\\'+self.user+'\\Pictures\\'
        self.video_column=self.simplefilelist.insert("",5,None,text='Видео',image=self.videos_img)
        self.sfl_dict[self.video_column]='C:\\Users\\'+self.user+'\\Videos\\'
        self.music_column=self.simplefilelist.insert("",6,None,text='Музыка',image=self.music_img)
        self.sfl_dict[self.music_column]='C:\\Users\\'+self.user+'\\Music\\'
        self.drive_column=self.simplefilelist.insert("",7,None,text='Диски',image=self.drive_img)
        self.sfl_dict[self.drive_column]='.'
        i=0
        for logical_drive in self.drives:
            i+=1
            logdrive=self.simplefilelist.insert(self.drive_column,i,None,text=logical_drive,image=self.drives_img)
            self.sfl_dict[logdrive]=logical_drive
        self.simplefilelist.insert("",8,None,text='                   ')
    def strhex(self,st):
        a='0123456789ABCDEF'
        return a[st//256]+a[st%256//16]+a[st%16]
    def check_size(self,fn):
        bsize=os.path.getsize(fn)
        if bsize>2**30:
            return str(bsize//2**30)+'Гб'
        if bsize>2**20:
            return str(bsize//2**20)+'Мб'
        if bsize>2**10:
            return str(bsize//2**10)+'Кб'
        else:
            return str(bsize)+'Б'
        
    def new_dir(self):
        newname=simpledialog.askstring('Введите имя новой папки!','Введите имя: ')
        os.makedirs(newname)
        self.full_files()
    def click2(self,event=None):
        el=self.sfl_dict[self.simplefilelist.selection()[0]]
        if el!='..':
            try:
                os.chdir(el)
                self.full_files()
            except:
                msgbox.showerror('Ошибка','Не удалось открыть папку или диск!')
    def click(self,event=None):
        el=self.files[self.listbox.selection()[0]]
        #if(1):
        try:
            if self.isfile(el):
                os.startfile(el)
            else:
                os.chdir(el+'\\')
                self.full_files()
        except:
            msgbox.showerror('Ошибка','Не удалось открыть файл или директорию!')
    def full_files(self):
        for it in self.files.keys():
            self.listbox.delete(it)
        files=['..']+list(os.listdir())
        self.images=[]
        self.files={}
        i=1
        for ob in files:
            if self.isfile(ob):
                if '.' in ob: res='.'+ob.split('.')[-1]
                else: res='Файл'
            else:
                res='Папка'
            if self.isfile(ob):
                try:
                    self.images+=[PhotoImage(file=self.img_lib+ob.split('.')[-1]+'.png')]
                    self.files[self.listbox.insert("",i,None,text=ob, values=(str(datetime.fromtimestamp(int(os.path.getctime(ob)))),res,self.check_size(ob)),image=self.images[-1])]=ob
                except:
                    self.images+=[PhotoImage(file=self.img_lib+'who.png')]
                    self.files[self.listbox.insert("",i,None,text=ob, values=(str(datetime.fromtimestamp(int(os.path.getctime(ob)))),res,self.check_size(ob)),image=self.images[-1])]=ob
            else:
                self.files[self.listbox.insert("",i,None,text=ob, values=(str(datetime.fromtimestamp(int(os.path.getctime(ob)))),res,self.check_size(ob)),image=self.dir_img)]=ob
            if i%100==99:
                self.window.update_idletasks()
                self.window.update()
            i+=1
        self.window.update()
        self.window.update_idletasks()
    def round_word(self,word,n):
        if len(word)>n-1:
            return word[:n-4]+'... '
        else:
            return word+' '*(n-len(word))
    def isfile(self,name):
        return os.path.isfile(name)
    def PASTE(self):
        if self.copy_or_cut==0:
            if self.isfile(self.copy_file):
                shutil.copyfile(self.copy_file, os.getcwd()+'\\'+self.copy_file.split('\\')[-1])
            else:
                shutil.copytree(self.copy_file, os.getcwd()+'\\'+self.copy_file.split('\\')[-1]+'\\')
        else:
            if self.isfile(self.copy_file):
                shutil.copyfile(self.copy_file, os.getcwd()+'\\'+self.copy_file.split('\\')[-1])
                os.remove(self.copy_file)
            else:
                shutil.copytree(self.copy_file, os.getcwd()+'\\'+self.copy_file.split('\\')[-1]+'\\')
                shutil.rmtree(self.copy_file)
        self.full_files()
    def COPY(self):
        el=self.files[self.listbox.selection()[0]]
        self.copy_file=os.getcwd()+'\\'+el
        self.copy_or_cut=0
    def CUT(self):
        el=self.files[self.listbox.selection()[0]]
        self.copy_file=os.getcwd()+'\\'+el
        self.copy_or_cut=1
    def RENAME(self):
        el=self.files[self.listbox.selection()[0]]
        newname=simpledialog.askstring('Введите новое имя!','Старое имя: '+el)
        os.rename(os.getcwd()+'\\'+el,os.getcwd()+'\\'+newname)
        self.full_files()
    def startfile(self,prgrm):
        el=self.files[self.listbox.selection()[0]]
        try:
            if self.isfile(el):
                os.popen(prgrm+' '+el)
        except:
                msgbox.showerror('Ошибка','Не удалось открыть папку или директорию!')
    def DELETE(self):
        el=self.files[self.listbox.selection()[0]]
        try:
            if self.isfile(el):
                os.remove(el)
                self.full_files()
            else:
                shutil.rmtree(el)
                self.full_files()
        except:
                msgbox.showerror('Ошибка','Не удалось удалить папку или директорию!')
    def OPEN(self):
        el=self.files[self.listbox.selection()[0]]
        try:
            if self.isfile(el):
                os.startfile(el)
            else:
                os.chdir(el)
                self.full_files()
        except:
            msgbox.showerror('Ошибка','Не удалось открыть папку или директорию!')
   
    def cmd_start(self):
        subprocess.Popen('cmd')
    def context(self,event=None):
        try:
            self.context_menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)
            
        except: pass
filesys=FileFrame(win,win)
filesys.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
win.mainloop()
```

Если нужно то папка и изображения в архиве: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1npYLiA-DcjQaZuX7qy0YJh5iFxuRKtzV/view?usp=sharing
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примерно так выглядит. Я правда показал только `C://`

Comment: А добавьте скриншот -- любопытно как выглядит GUI с этим деревом

Comment: @gil9red , я добавил

Comment: Спасибо большое, попробую для себя реализовать!!

Comment: @FotonPC, спасибо. Круто выглядит :)

Comment: @Gersa, не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Просмотрел, сложновато для меня. У меня то простая программа