# Отображение данных на экране

Tags: python, tkinter, smtp, imap

У меня есть метод в классе, который выдает все id писем с почты. Мне необходимо сделать так, что бы письма отображались в таком же виде как и на электронной почте (построчно), что бы можно было скролить этот список и что бы строка с письмом была кликабельна. Для этого использую библиотеку tkinter.

```
def get_inbox(mail):

    folder = [re.sub(r'.*?("\[G[^"]*").*', r'\1', f.decode("UTF-8")) for f in mail.list()[1] if
              br"\All " in f][0]
    mail.select(folder)

    typ, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
```

У меня не хватает знаний как это сделать. Если кто то поможет буду очень благодарен! Вопрос может быть не много не корректным заранее за это извиняюсь.

Comment: Тут можно использовать контрол Treeview, посмотрите в интернете примеры. Вот тут целый файловый менеджер, например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1230906/1365 , но для начала лучше простые примеры взять за основу.

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю